# Pandas data frame Styler keeps overwriting previous styles in the data frame

Tags: python, pandas, background-color

I have a Pandas data frame with a couple of columns.

```
# Example Data frame

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,15,10,47,35],      
    'B':["Mac","Mac","Mac","Mac","Mac"],
    'C':["Dog","Dog","Cat","Dog","Tiger"], 
    'D':["CDN", "USD", "CDN", "Pe", "Dr"]
})
```

I want to color each element in columns 'B', 'C', 'D' based on the relative frequency of each respective element within the column. For example, the relative frequency of "CDN" in the 'D' column is 2/5 = 0.4.

These are my criteria for the color based on the relative frequency:

| Relative frequency | Color |
| --- | --- |
| Greater than or equal to 0.90 | Green |
| Less than 0.90 and greater than or equal to 0.30 | Yellow |
| Less than 0.30 | Red |

Since the relative frequency of "CDN" within the 'D' column is 0.4, then, that cell would be assigned a background color of Yellow.

I know how to find the relative frequency of each element within a column and how to color the elements.

**My problem is that the style of one column keeps getting overwritten by the style of another column.** Here is my code:

```
RemvColOfInterest = ['B', 'C', 'D'] # These are the columns whose elements we want to color

lstcollectionOverallRelFreqs = ['some relative frequencies'] # You don't have to worry about this

colIndexList = [] # This is the index of each of the columns in RemvColOfInterest
s = 0

while (s < len(RemvColOfInterest)):
    colIndexList.append(s)
    s = s + 1
    
tempdf = copy.copy(df)
    
for g, h in zip( RemvColOfInterest, colIndexList ): 
    df = tempdf.style.applymap(highlight_cell, lstFreq = lstcollectionOverallRelFreqs, colIndex = h, subset = pd.IndexSlice[:, [g]])

# If I output my df to an excel file:
df.to_excel("My file path", index = False)

def highlight_cell(value, lstFreq, colIndex):
    Freq = determine_Freq(lstFreq[colIndex]) # All you need to know is that this is the function that finds the relative frequency associated with the element/cell
            
    threshold1 = 0.90
    threshold2 = 0.30
    
    if (Freq >= threshold1):
        return 'background-color: green;'
    elif ((Freq < threshold1) and (Freq >= threshold2)): 
        return 'background-color: yellow;'
    else:
        return 'background-color: red;'
```

In the excel file, only the elements in column 'D' have the background-color. Columns 'B' and 'C' just have the usual white background color. This leads me to believe that the style for columns 'B' and 'C' were each overwritten by the style from column 'D'. How do I prevent this from happening.

I believe this is the problematic line (when it's in the for loop cause the style of `df` gets replaced with a new style during each iteration):

```
df = tempdf.style.applymap(highlight_cell, lstFreq = lstcollectionOverallRelFreqs, colIndex = h, subset = pd.IndexSlice[:, [g]])
```

The thing is, I'm only considering one column at a time when applying the style (the subset parameter). So, why do the styles of different columns overwrite one another. If instead of the above line, I do:

```
df[g] = tempdf.style.applymap(highlight_cell, lstFreq = lstcollectionOverallRelFreqs, colIndex = h, subset = pd.IndexSlice[:, [g]])
```

I get `pandas.io.formats.style.Styler object at 0x00000...` for each of the cells in columns 'B', 'C' and 'D'. Any pointers/suggestions?

This is what the output excel file from the example should look like:

[image]

Comment: If you want to consider one column at a time, use `apply` and build the function on the columns, not the cells, instead of `applymap` which only have cell context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try (you must have installed [`xlsxwriter`](https://pypi.org/project/XlsxWriter/)):

More info about [conditional formatting here](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_conditional_formats.html).

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": [1, 15, 10, 47, 35],
        "B": ["Mac", "Mac", "Mac", "Mac", "Mac"],
        "C": ["Dog", "Dog", "Cat", "Dog", "Tiger"],
        "D": ["CDN", "USD", "CDN", "Pe", "Dr"],
    }
)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter("out.xlsx", engine="xlsxwriter")
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Sheet1", index=False)

workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets["Sheet1"]

format1 = workbook.add_format({"bg_color": "#98fb98", "font_color": "#111111"})
format2 = workbook.add_format({"bg_color": "#ffff31", "font_color": "#111111"})
format3 = workbook.add_format({"bg_color": "#fe2712", "font_color": "#111111"})

for c in ['B', 'C', 'D']:
    vals = df[c].value_counts() / len(df)
    for i, v in zip(vals.index, vals):
        f = {"type": "cell", "criteria": "==", "value": f'"{i}"', "format": format1 if v > 0.9 else (format2 if v > 0.3 else format3)}
        r = f"{c}2:{c}{len(df)+1}"
        worksheet.conditional_format(r, f)

writer.close()
```

Creates `out.xlsx` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

---

EDIT: `openpyxl` version:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": [1, 15, 10, 47, 35],
        "B": ["Mac", "Mac", "Mac", "Mac", "Mac"],
        "C": ["Dog", "Dog", "Cat", "Dog", "Tiger"],
        "D": ["CDN", "USD", "CDN", "Pe", "Dr"],
    }
)

format1 = "background-color: #98fb98; color: #111111"
format2 = "background-color: #ffff31; color: #111111"
format3 = "background-color: #fe2712; color: #111111"


def fn(x):
    if x.name == "A":
        return [""] * len(x)

    vals = x.value_counts() / len(x)
    return [
        format1 if v > 0.9 else (format2 if v > 0.3 else format3)
        for v in map(vals.get, x)
    ]


with pd.ExcelWriter("out.xlsx", engine="openpyxl") as writer:
    df.style.apply(fn).to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name="Sheet1")
```

Comment: Hi, I am unable to install xlsxwriter in my Anaconda environment. I do, however, have openpyxl installed. Could I just use that?

Comment: One quick question-- what does this code line do: for v in map(vals.get, x)

Comment: @Diamoniner12345 `for v in map(vals.get, x)`: This will iterate over each value of pd.Series `x` (the column B, C and D) and map this value to computed frequency (that I need to know for correct coloring).